# iPlanet instance keep crashing - only error in weblogic log "Connection reset by peer: socket write error" is seen

Tags: weblogic

I have a Web(iPlanet6.1) - Weblogic(11g) - MS SQL (2008) setup all based on Windows 2008.

There are couple of occasions, the web instance keep crashing even the web server is rebooted. The only way to stop the crash is do a DB failover. And the only error(lots of occurrences) can be seen are in weblogic log i.e socket write error, during the period.

Much appreciated to advise some hint on what is the cause and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance,

brightcp

```
####<Jul 8, 2014 11:17:10 PM GMT> <Error> <HTTP> <server1> <frontend> <[ACTIVE]
ExecuteThread: '48' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <>
<1404861430312> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@700633104[app:frontendapp module:soap path:/soap 
spec-version:null]] Root cause of ServletException.
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error building response envelope: java.net.SocketException:     
Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at org.apache.soap.server.http.RPCRouterServlet.doPost(RPCRouterServlet.java:396)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run    
(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.amadeus.ocg.framework.session.multisession.MultiSessionFilter.doFilter
(MultiSessionFilter.java:44)
    at com.amadeus.ocg.framework.statistics.StatsFilter.doFilter(StatsFilter.java:230)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun
(WebAppServletContext.java:3739)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run
(WebAppServletContext.java:3705)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute    
(WebAppServletContext.java:2282)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2181)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```